# Vue-tables-2(vuex) reactivity not working

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-tables-2

I've several components using [vue-tables-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2) but one of them is not updating the table until I change the route.

**component**

```
    <template>
//..
    <div class="table-responsive" >
       <v-client-table ref="table" name="vCardTable" 
          :data="vCardTableData.data" 
          :columns="vCardTableData.headers" 
          :options="vCardTableData.options"/>
    </div> 
//..
    </template>
<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "VCard",
  computed: {
    ...mapState("commons", ["user"]),
    ...mapGetters({ vCardTableData: "vCard/vCardTableData" })
  },
  mounted() {
    var self = this;
    self.$nextTick(() => {
      self.$store.dispatch("vCard/getVCards"); <-- GET TABLE DATA
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

**store**

```
const state = {
    vCardTableData: {
        data: [],
        headers: [
           //..
        ],
        options: {
            filterable: false,
            preserveState: false,
            headings: {
                //..
            },
            texts: {
                //..
            },
            pagination: {
                dropdown: true,
            },
            templates: {
                //..
            },
        },
    }
}

const getters = {
    vCardTableData: state => state.vCardTableData
}

const actions = {
    getVCards({commit, dispatch}) {
            return api.request("get", "getvcards").then(response => {
                setTimeout(() => {  
                    commit("setVCardTableData", response.data.vcards);
                }, 300);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}

const mutations = {
    clearTableData: (state) => {
        if (state.vCardTableData.data) {
            state.vCardTableData.data = [];
        }
    },
    setVCardTableData : (state, vCardTableData) => state.vCardTableData.data = vCardTableData   
}
```

As you can see in this image the table has data:

[image]
But the view is refreshed when the route changes:

[image]

> 02/05/2018

Well now I've seen that if I modify the state directly in the component with promises it works:

```
this.$store.dispatch("vCard/getVCards", []).then((responseData)=>{
       this.$store.state.vCard.vCardTableData.data = responseData;
  });
```

**Does anyone know why?**
Thank you

Comment: may be because it requires some kind of "deep" tracking. look up that keyword with vuex.

Comment: try `useVuex=true` like `Vue.use(VueTables.ClientTable, [options = {}], [useVuex = true], [theme = 'bulma'], [template = 'default'])`, also I tested similiar codes as yours, it seems working fine..

Comment: *"but one of them is not updating the table until I change the route."*, do you think it should change in response to what instead? Click of a button? Call of an action? If so, which one?

Comment: Is calling an action  ->   self.$nextTick(() => {
      self.$store.dispatch("vCard/getVCards");
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My last answer was wrong, I did not remember that I had changed the `vuex` parameter of the table to false. I don't know why but doing a push it works:

```
setVCardTableData : (state, vCardTableData) => {
    vCardTableData.forEach(tableData => {
            state.vCardTableData.data.push(tableData);   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a probably a reactivity issue. (See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats for detailed explanation.)

Changing how you set the object value in your mutation to this should solve the problem

```
setVCardTableData: (state, vCardTableData) => state.vCardTableData = {
    ...state.vCardTableData,
    data: vCardTableData
}
```

Basically, this creates a new object so that Vue knows that the object has been updated. In Javasript, object is passed by reference, meaning that `vCardTableData` don't store the object, it stores the reference to the object. You could think of it as a pointer/address that points to the object in memory. When you change a child property in the object, the reference remains unchanged, so Vue does not know that the object has been updated. Creating a new object makes sure that the object reference is updated.

This is also explained in *Mutations Follow Vue's Reactivity Rules*
in https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues. Like others have already mention it is probably a reactivity problem. You can use `Vue.set()` to ensure that your properties are reactive when setting the state values.

```
setVCardTableData: (state, vCardTableData) => {
    Vue.set(state.vCardTableData, 'data', vCardTableData);
}
```

Check the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) for this method.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a deep object, you need to use Object.assign in your mutation

```
setVCardTableData: (state, vCardTableData) => Object.assign(state.vCardTableData.data, vCardTableData)
```